# Change localhost to hosts alias

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

Why when I add to my hosts file alias to localhost `my.host` and run page in IntelliJ IDEA by browsers buttons

[image]

it is opening with url: `localhost:port/` but when I change it to `my.host:port/` I see **404**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is by design, it works fine if your project name is the same as the hostname, you will need to adjust the URL:

```
http://localhost:port/projectname/ => http://projectname:port/
```

Add `projectname` to `hosts` and it should work.

Project name can be changed in the Project Structure dialog.